# How to avoid skipped frames with AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a method called `table()` which generates a table with 600 rows. When I run this method in `onCreate()` i.e. in the main UI thread, I receive a message from log that says:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."
```

I found out, in order to avoid skipped frames, I should use `AsyncTask`. But, I don't know how to implement table generation in background ? I can't put `table()` method in `doInBackground(Void... params)`, because `doInBackground` doesn't work with UI, but I also can't put this method in `onPostExecute`,  because it will give me skipped frames.

What is the right way to implement table generation in `AsyncTask` ?

Here is code of table method, I run it in `onCreate()`

```
public void table(){
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScroll = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tableLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    LayoutParams cellsParam = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    cellsParam.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < 600; i++){
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            TextView wayTextView = new TextView(this);
            wayTextView.setText("text" + i);
            wayTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            wayTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            row.addView(wayTextView, cellsParam);

            tableLayout.addView(row);
        }
    horizontalScroll.addView(tableLayout);
    scrollView.addView(horizontalScroll);
    setContentView(scrollView);
}
```

Comment: Since you have many rows, which, I suppose, are in a ScrollView, have you considered using a ListView (instead of a TableLayout) with an Adapter to load items (here, rows) only as needed?

Comment: No, I need exactly a table. The code which I have written above is just a simple example. In reality I will generate table with more columns and in the setText() I will put data from database. So, I need exactly a table.

Comment: Why are you creating views instead of using a view that's defined in XML?

Comment: Kevin Krumwiede, you mean why am I creating the table from code ?

Answer (score 0):

there is a practice called "[loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)" that will help you (but instead of doing it for 'optimization', we're doing it here to divide up the loop into 'bite size' chunks that won't block the UI thread.)

Make 6 tasks, each that does 100 rows:, or 10 tasks of 60 rows (whatever happens to work best for your app.)

**I've now tested this, and it works as intended**

The 'static' count at the top is what counts from: 0 -> (N-1)

```
package com.example.mike.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int totalCount = 600;
        int numTasks = 10;

        int division = totalCount / numTasks ;

        // where did the other loop
        for (int i = 0; i < numTasks ; i++) {
            new UpdateRowsTask(this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, Integer.valueOf(division));
        }
    }

    public void doLog(String str) {
        Log.d("TEST", str);
    }

    private static class UpdateRowsTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
        int maxCount ;
        MainActivity _activity;

        public UpdateRowsTask(MainActivity activity) {
            _activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            maxCount = params[0]; // adjustable
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            do {
                _activity.doLog("" + count);
                count++;
            }
             while  ((count % maxCount) != 0 ) ;
        }
    }   
}
```

I have 'log.d()' as my "UI thread" operation, but you can easily make it your adding of rows.

Comment: 1. You defined the result type as being `Void`, but the type of the `doInBackground()` method is `ContactsListCursorAdapter` when it should be `Void`.

2. AsyncTasks (since Donut) use a pool of 5 background threads, so the order of many AsyncTasks cannot be guaranteed. EDIT: My bad. It was changed back in Honeycomb.

Comment: I don't see the point of this solution since by default AsyncTasks run sequentially: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @IanNewson The 'ContactsListCursorAdapter' was due to me grabbing someone elses's AsyncTask and editing to work. Yes, I cleaned up the executor, and realized I was remembering too far back about the threading.

Comment: I've updated it with working code now. Once I optimized it, it became much cleaner and clear cut what it was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Having read more about AsyncTask, I concluded that AsyncTask doesn't fit to solve my problem. Because with AsyncTask I can't update UI in `doInBackground` and run `table()` method in `onPostExecute` is also wrong, because doing so, I again do too much work in main thread and again will receive skipped frames.